# how to calculate the covar matrix for mahadistance

Tags: c++, opencv, similarity

I am trying to implement **mahalanobis distance** using OpenCV and VC++ 2010.

I know the algorithm for it, the function.

```
(x-mean)^T*inv(covarmatrix)*(x-mean)
```

But when I implement it in OpenCV it just gives errors over and over.

this is my code where I am calculating the covariance matrix.

```
int Main(){

    Mat Image;
    Mat, Cov,mean;
    float samples=1920000;
    calcCovarMatrix(image,samples,covmat,mean,CV_COVAR_NORMAL);
}
```

the `calcCovarMatrix` gives error:

```
no instance of overloaded function calcCovarMatrix matches the argument list.
```

After I would then do

```
vec3b pixel;
icovar=covmat^-1;
mdist = mahalanobis(vec3b,mean,icovar);
```

Note: I calculate mahalanobis distance without square root, but the above function does square root, how comes and also I will square it to make it fair as I did the same to get the threshold distance.

thanks

Comment: Looking at the documentation it seeems that the function takes an int as second argument while you are passing it as float.

Comment: i tried int sample 1420000 but still same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument should be a Mat* so it should be &image

See http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#void calcCovarMatrix(const Mat* samples, int nsamples, Mat& covar, Mat& mean, int flags, int ctype)

Comment: i don't understand when i see these Mat* thinking its same as Mat. Genius i didn't know that, now everytime there is a * i add & thanks how about the rest of the code does it seem fine to work to calculate mahalanobis distance vec3b pixel;
icovar=covmat^-1;
mdist = mahalanobis(vec3b,mean,icovar);

Comment: Hi could you help me with this further i did what you recommend then did icov=cov.inverse();  calcovar(&image, covar, mean, CV_COVAR_NORMAL). but i get an unhandled exception error i have posted a detailed question on this with code would appreciate your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085862/chroma-keying-using-mahalanobis my post about this problem in detail

Comment: It was poor form to unaccept this answer just because you have further problems. I will not answer that other post unless you reaccept this, I notice you are making use of this answer.

Comment: it was because the error resulted even following this answer i thought because you answered this question you weren't going to answer my other question which continues from this.